# What is GPG equivalent of ssh-add?

Tags: linux, gpg, ssh-agent

When using password-secured SSH keys I can use `ssh-add` to preemptively unlock a key before it needs to be used and have it cached in `ssh-agent` for future use. What is a GPG equivalent of `ssh-add`? I know how to increase the caching time of GPG keys once they are unlocked but I don't know how to unlock a GPG key before it needs to be used, other than artificially issuing a command that will trigger the unlock, e.g. `git commit` (I have commit signing enabled).